# How to rewrite this normal derivative in a sphere as a radial derivative?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, vector-analysis

I've come across the following line of working in a set of notes on the mean value theorem for harmonic functions:
$$\int_{\partial B_r(x)} \frac{\partial u}{\partial \nu}\, dS = r^{n-1} \int_{\partial B_1(0)} \frac{\partial u}{\partial r}(x+ry) \, dS(y)$$
What I don't understand is how the two derivatives are converted into one another. The $r^{n-1}$ seems to come from the Jacobian determinant $(=r^n)$ and the factor of $\frac{1}{r}$ which appears in the normal vector to the ball of radius $r$. I think this should leave you with an integrand of $\nabla u \cdot (x+ry)$ but I'm not sure how this is equivalent to the integrand in the expression above. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The $n$ dimensional spherical coordinates Jacobian always has a factor $r^{n-1}$, not $r^n$ e.g. polar coordinates $rd\theta$, 3d spherical coordinates $r^2d\Omega$, etc. The "volume" of a boundary element usually scales this way.

Comment: We aren't converting to spherical coordinates though, are we? I figured we were looking at a transformation given by $a_i = x_i + ry_i$ for $1 \leq i \leq n$, where the integration on the right is w.r.t. $(a_1, \dots, a_n) \in \partial B_r(x)$ and the integration on the left is w.r.t $(y_1, \dots, y_n) \in \partial B_1(0)$. Then the Jacobian would be triangular with $\frac{\partial a_i}{\partial y_i} = r$ on the diagonal, giving it a determinant of $r^n$. Where am I going wrong?